# javascript oop multiple classes

Tags: javascript, oop

Hi Im having problems with javascript! i have main.js and Model.js. Model.js is a javascript oop class in need to access its functions in main.js how do i do that? I keep getting an error that Model is not defined. Are there tools needed for this to work or something is wrong in the code?

Model.js

```
Model = {};   

Model.init = function() {
    alert("model");
}

Model.getList = function(){
var list;
$.ajax(
    { 

    url:'???',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(data)
    {
    list=data;
    }
    error: function(data)
    {
    alert("error");
    }
    });
    return list;
}
```

main.js

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

    var testins=new Model();
    var list=Model.getList();

    alert("result: "+testins); 
}
```

I really could use some help.

so I tried MrCode approach and for experimental reasons put the code in one file because main.js still could not access the Model.js file.

main.js

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

 function onDeviceReady() {
     alert("aaa"); //first

    var testins=new Model();
    var list=testins.getList(); 

    alert("result: "+testins); // third

    alert("list"+list); //fourth
     }

    function Model()
    {
    this.init = function()
    {
        alert("Model");
    }
    this.getList = function()
     {
      var list;
      $.ajax(
          { 

          url:'??',
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',

          success: function(data)
          {
          list=data;
          alert("success"+list);  //fifth
          },
          error: function(data)
          {
          alert("error");
          }
          });
      alert("success"+list);  //second
          return(list);
    }
   }
```

but following the alerts i see the that the $.ajax part is done last.

Comment: What do you mean "following the alerts I see the ajax is done last"?? Your alert with the ajax data is last so will always show last. The call happens after the `aaa` alert but the result may not be retrieved for some time after that depending on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
function Model() { // this is the "constructor"
}
```

And replace

```
Model.init = function() {
```

by

```
Model.prototype.init = function() { // provide the function to all instances
```

(and the same for getList)

This will enable

- you to call `new Model()`
- the `init` function to be inherited by the objects you create with `new Model()`.

Use it like this :

```
var testins=new Model(); // create an instance
var list=testins.getList(); // call the instance method
```

You may be interested by [this MDN document about prototype and inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Comment: did as you said but sill i get an error "Web Console(6382): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getList' of undefined at file:///asset/www/jquery/main.js:40
"

Comment: Did you really call `testins.getList()` (and not `Model.getList()`) ?

Comment: really. i have added the scripts in the order so main would be last and made the changes to model.js as well as main.js but still get the error.

Comment: You have other problems in your code. [Read that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475269/variable-doesnt-get-returned-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
function Model()
{
    // define public methods
    this.init = function()
    {
        alert("Model");
    }

    this.getList = function()
    {
        var list;
        $.ajax(
            { 

            url:'???',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(data)
            {
            list=data;
            }
            error: function(data)
            {
            alert("error");
            }
            });
            return list;
    }
}

var testins = new Model(); // create an instance of Model()
var list = testins.getList(); // call its method
```

Comment: Tried your approach but i had problems because every time i try it the $.ajax is done last so the list is empty

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your logic or ajax call rather than the OOP design. Post your updated code and I'll take a look.