# Issue with code inner variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like the one stated below, please how do I get the value for (getData), using a code like:

```
var instanceArray = myGraph.getInstances(component)
```

I was thinking `myGraph.getInstances(component).getData` will do it, but it failed

```
this.getInstances = function(component) {
    var getData = {};
        $.ajax({
            url: "/rpc/alerts2/commonObj_rpc.cfc?method=getInstances",
            data: {"component":component},
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                getData = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log("hey");
                var $render_component_instance = $("#instances").empty();
                $("#instances").append($("<option />").val("all").text("All Instances (Summed)"));
                $.each(getData, function (cIndex, cItem){
                    var $instance = $("<option />").val(cItem.si_instance).text(cItem.si_label.toUpperCase());
                    $render_component_instance.append($instance);
                })
                $("#instances").multiselect("refresh");
            }
        });
};`
```

Comment: What framework are you using? What is myGraph?

Comment: myGraph is just an instance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable doesn't get returned JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475269/variable-doesnt-get-returned-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, the get is asynchronous. `getInstances` returns before the GET completes, so it's impossible for `getInstances` to return the data. (See further note below.)

You have (at least) three options:

1. Use a callback
2. Return a blank object that will get populated later, and have the code that needs it poll it periodically
3. Use a synchronous get (not a good idea)

#### 1. Use a callback

What you can do instead is accept a callback, and then call it when the data arrives:

```
this.getInstances = function(component, callback) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/rpc/alerts2/commonObj_rpc.cfc?method=getInstances",
        data: {"component":component},
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            var getData = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log("hey");
            var $render_component_instance = $("#instances").empty();
            $("#instances").append($("<option />").val("all").text("All Instances (Summed)"));
            $.each(getData, function (cIndex, cItem){
                var $instance = $("<option />").val(cItem.si_instance).text(cItem.si_label.toUpperCase());
                $render_component_instance.append($instance);
            })
            $("#instances").multiselect("refresh");
            callback(getData);
        }
    });
};
```

And call it like this:

```
myGraph.getInstances(component, function(data) {
    // Use the data here
});
```

#### 2. Return a blank object that will get populated later

Alternately, you can return an object which will be blank to start with, but which you'll add the data to as a property later. This may be closest to what you were looking for, from your comments below. Basically, there's no way to access a function's local variables from outside the function, but you *can* return an object and then add a property to it later.

```
this.getInstances = function(component) {

    var obj = {};

    $.ajax({
        url: "/rpc/alerts2/commonObj_rpc.cfc?method=getInstances",
        data: {"component":component},
        type: "POST",
        async: false,    // <==== Note the change
        success: function(data) {
            var getData = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log("hey");
            var $render_component_instance = $("#instances").empty();
            $("#instances").append($("<option />").val("all").text("All Instances (Summed)"));
            $.each(getData, function (cIndex, cItem){
                var $instance = $("<option />").val(cItem.si_instance).text(cItem.si_label.toUpperCase());
                $render_component_instance.append($instance);
            })
            $("#instances").multiselect("refresh");

            // Make the data available on the object
            obj.getData = getData;
        }
    });

    return obj; // Will be empty when we return it
};
```

And call it like this:

```
var obj = myGraph.getInstances(component);

// ...later...
if (obj.getData) {
    // We have the data, use it
}
else {
    // We still don't have the data
}
```

#### 3. Use a synchronous get

I **do not** recommend this, but you could make the call synchronous. Note that synchronous ajax requests will go away in a future version of jQuery. But just for completeness:

```
this.getInstances = function(component) {

    var getData;    
    $.ajax({
        url: "/rpc/alerts2/commonObj_rpc.cfc?method=getInstances",
        data: {"component":component},
        type: "POST",
        async: false,    // <==== Note the change
        success: function(data) {
            var getData = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log("hey");
            var $render_component_instance = $("#instances").empty();
            $("#instances").append($("<option />").val("all").text("All Instances (Summed)"));
            $.each(getData, function (cIndex, cItem){
                var $instance = $("<option />").val(cItem.si_instance).text(cItem.si_label.toUpperCase());
                $render_component_instance.append($instance);
            })
            $("#instances").multiselect("refresh");
        }
    });

    return getData;
};
```

And call it like this:

```
var getData = myGraph.getInstances(component);
```

But again, I don't advocate that. Synchronous ajax calls lock up the UI of the browser, leading to a bad user experience.

Comment: Can you explain the call please

Comment: @deetu: Happy to, but what specifically...?

Comment: i know i can easy get the data using synchronous, but im trying to just retrieve the getdata, so the instance doesnt to run the lines after it

Comment: @deetu: I'm sorry, I don't understand that sentence. What does "...so the instance doesn't to run the lines after it..." mean?

Comment: i just need the data from getData, thats all

Comment: @deetu: First off, sorry, I messed up my initial two examples (I set the wrong one of them to be `async: false`!). So I've fixed that. I also added a new example (#2) which may be what you're looking for. Basically, there's no way to access a local variable from outside a function, but there are alternatives that do something similar.