# Using jQuery within a function to return text of a file

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Variable doesn’t get returned from AJAX function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475269/variable-doesnt-get-returned-from-ajax-function)
>   [How to return the response from an AJAX call from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function)

I'm building a basic, local-only app. First time using jQuery - and I'll be bringing in a templating system once I settle on one (Leaning towards jsrender or mustache).

I'm trying to set things up so that a page can be loaded (Let's say home.html) and within it have it call upon a function that pulls data from a file and returns it.

I have this code

```
function grabFile(name) {
    $.get(name+'.txt', function(data) {
        ...
    });
}
```

If I place a `Console.log(data)` in the middle, the console shows me the contents of the file. Success. Similar success if I use a `$('#output').html(data);` there in the middle.

But I'd like to set it up so that I can use a `<script>grabFile(name);</script>` anywhere in an HTML file to call it. Using `return data;` in the middle, to the jQuery newbie, seemed like the solution... but that doesn't work.

Help?

Comment: Use `$.ajax` with `async: false`

Comment: Or better : change the whole architecture. "a function that pulls data from a file and returns it" isn't good practice in javascript.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475269/variable-doesnt-get-returned-from-ajax-function

Comment: Dystroy, I'm more than willing to learn - if there's a better way, please, point me in the right direction as an answer?