# jQuery variable scope in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with jQuery.

I wanted to get the real width/height of an `img`.
Now I used this function to get it:

```
var imageSize = function(image) {
    var realImageSize = { };

    $("<img/>") // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
    .attr("src", $(image).attr("src"))
    .load(function() {
        realImageSize.width = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
        realImageSize.height = this.height; // work for in memory images.

        alert(realImageSize['height']); // Valid height
    });

    alert(realImageSize['height']); // Undefined

    return realImageSize;
}
```

So I'm copying the image in memory, and then I get and set the images real size in the `.load` method.

Now, the problem is that the `var realImageSize` variable isn't available in this scope for some reason. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: `load()` is asynchronous, and as such will have exited before your callback is called. What you are trying to do is not possible. You need to handle all logic dependant on the `load()` within the callback.

Comment: It's similar (maybe a duplicate, maybe not) to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475269/variable-doesnt-get-returned-from-ajax-function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a problem of scope, it's fine, but a problem of synchronicity : you're reading the value before the load callback has been executed.

The callback you give as argument to `load` isn't executed immediately but only after the image has been loaded.

The usual solution is to not return a value but provide a callback :

```
var fetchImageSize = function(image, callback) {
    $("<img/>") // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
    .load(function() {
        var realImageSize = { };
        realImageSize.width = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
        realImageSize.height = this.height; // work for in memory images.
        callback(realImageSize);
    }).attr("src", image.src);
};

fetchImageSize(myImage, function(realImageSize){
    alert(realImageSize['height']); // NOT Undefined
});
```

Note that you should always set the src *after* you set the `onload` callback. Some browsers, if you have the image in cache, might not call the onload callback if you set it after you set the source.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. Is there a way to 'wait' until the `.load` is finished?

Comment: No : you have to execute the code in the callback or in a function called from the callback.

Comment: @NSAddict no. But you can take a callback as argument or you can return a promise.

Answer (score 2):

your second alert is called before the load function is completed.use callbacks...

try this

```
var imageSize = function(image,callback) {
  var realImageSize = { };

  $("<img/>") // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
  .attr("src", $(image).attr("src"))
  .load(function() {
    realImageSize.width = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
    realImageSize.height = this.height; // work for in memory images.

    alert(realImageSize['height']); // Valid height
    callback(realImageSize);
  });


}

imageSize(img, function(realImageSize) {
   alert(realImageSize.height);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this won't work, because a style `width` could be applied to the img.

Answer (score 2):

Use a callback. The other answers are explaining the asynchronous stuff, I'm not repeating :-)

```
var imageSize = function(image, callback) {
.
.
.
    .load(function() {
        realImageSize.width = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
        realImageSize.height = this.height; // work for in memory images.

        callback(realImageSize);
    });
```

Then, you can call the function like this:

```
imageSize(img, function(size) {
    alert(size.height);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem for Javascript programmer who come from other languages. Javascript uses an execution model called Asynchronous calls. In a nutshell when you register a function for the `.load()` event, the execution will of the function will be postponed to **when the image has been loaded** while the rest of the function body (ie. second `alert()`) executes immediately:

```
var imageSize = function(image) {
    //runs now
    var realImageSize = { };

    //runs now
    $("<img/>") // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
    .attr("src", $(image).attr("src"))
    .load(function() {
        //this code can run say 5 sec later
        realImageSize.width = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
        realImageSize.height = this.height; // work for in memory images.

        alert(realImageSize['height']); // Valid height
    });

    //runs now. The realImageSize variable is yet to be created in 5 sec
    alert(realImageSize['height']); // Undefined

    //runs now
    return realImageSize;
}
```

A common pattern to solve this kind of issue is to pass a callback to the function that is going to take long.

```
//** Get an image URL and a callback function that will be called when the image is loaded and the size is detected
function imageSize ( src, callback ) {
    $("<img src="' + src + '"/>").load( function () {
        //here we call the callback which will be called when the image is loaded
        callback({
            width: this.width,
            height: this.height
        });
    });
}

imageSize( 'my/image/path.png', function ( imageSize ) {
    //this callback function will be called when the image is loaded
    alert( 'width: ' + imageSize.width + ', height: ' + imageSize.height );
});
```