# adding to array from inside ajax call javascript - undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I declare an array then make an ajax call which returns multiple rows of values. I'm trying to add the id of these rows to that array that i declared previously, but it keeps returning undefined.

```
  var recipeIds = Array();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        cache:true,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){
                             recipeIds.push(item.id);
         });
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("Ajax not working - recipies in cat");
        }
    });
    alert("array0 = " + recipeIds[0]);
```

any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable doesn't get returned from AJAX function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475269/variable-doesnt-get-returned-from-ajax-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you alert, the ajax call hasn't yet returned. It's asynchronous, meaning the ajax call will happen *after* the alert.

You must use the result from inside the `success` callback you give to the ajax function.

Comment: oh right. thanks.i'm a bit thick sometimes! i do however need to use this variable... actually to make other ajax calls. any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: Yes, do your other calls from inside the success callback or from a function you call from the success callback. I give an example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12475285/263525).