# Why prototype function returns nothing in javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

My javascript prototype function like below;

```
ServerDataEngine.prototype.ExecuteCommand = function(command)
{
  try 
    {
       var result;
       $.get(command, function (data) {
           result = jQuery.parseJSON(atob(data));
           console.log(result);
       });
       return result;
    }
  catch (Exception) 
    {
       throw (new Exception("Can not connect to server"));
    }
}
```

And I call this function like this;

```
ServerDataEngine.prototype.ExecuteQuery = function (query) 
  {
     console.log(this.ExecuteCommand(query));
  }
```

In `ExecuteCommand`, everything is ok, but in `ExecuteQuery`, `console.log(this.ExecuteCommand(command))` line produces `undefined`.

What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to the world of asynchronous JavaScript! Where you *can't return* results of an async operation. Try researching about asynchronous JS and how *callbacks* are used instead of returns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable doesn't get returned from AJAX function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475269/variable-doesnt-get-returned-from-ajax-function)

Comment: I suggest the use of .done() after the .get()

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are treating an Asynchronous Request as a synchronous one. You are returning the value before the Ajax call ever returns a value. It is not going to be able to work that way.

Comment: Is there a solution? like adding async:false parameter?