# Javascript setInterval doesn't update timestamp used inside

Tags: javascript, html, variables, setinterval, updates

I am using setInterval in Javascript. For a simple example I tried to update a time displayed.

```
var tim = new Date();
function loadLog(){
    document.getElementById('timebox').innerHTML=tim.getTime();
}
window.setInterval(loadLog, 1000);
```

But the time is not updated. Why? How can I update the variable inside setInterval?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a new date each time instead of always showing the same one :

```
function loadLog(){
    var tim = new Date();
    document.getElementById('timebox').innerHTML=tim.getTime();
}
window.setInterval(loadLog, 1000);
```

Comment: Great, works with the time. When I am using jQuery, why doesn't this update as well?                                          `function loadLog(){
 var test;
 $.get('get_feedback.php', function(data) {
    test=data;
 });
 document.getElementById('chatbox').innerHTML=test;
}

window.setInterval(loadLog, 2500);

Comment: Because $.get is asynchronous. Use `function loadLog(){var test; $.get('get_feedback.php', function(data) { test=data;document.getElementById('chatbox').innerHTML=test; });
}window.setInterval(loadLog, 2500);`

Comment: See this related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475269/variable-doesnt-get-returned-from-ajax-function

Comment: But using setInterval for that is wrong : if your network or server is slow, your page will explode. Use setTimeout (if needed ask another question, it's unrelated and painful to code in comments).

Comment: But the variable "data" is not updated (the return from the get_feedback.php changes). Is that not possible because it is async?

Comment: I don't understand your comment but the answer is probably in the link I gave, did you understand it ?

Comment: I didn't so I asked a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618183/updating-html-code-with-javascript-when-php-return-changed