# Updating html code with javascript when php return changed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, callback

I want to continuously update an html document using the return of a php file. Therefore I need to use the jQuery function:

```
$.get('returnfunction.php', function(data) { 
test=data;
document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML=test; 
});
```

How can I call this function continuously in javascript? setInterval seems not proper for this asynchronous function.

Thanks

Comment: in setInterval, the "data" variable is not updated.If you know a solution that works please let me know, it doesnt need to be very efficient or something. The update should be between 1-5 seconds

Comment: The Javascript timers are not accurate because they are designed to yeild to other events that are going on in the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with calling an asynchronous function using `setInterval` is that the unanswered requests might accumulate if the server or the network is slow.

Here's how you might do it :

```
(function doOne(){
    $.get('returnfunction.php', function(data) { 
       test=data; 
       document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML=test;
       setTimeout(doOne, 1000);
    }); 
})();
```

This way the next call to `$.get` occurs one second after the server has answered the last call.

You might also want to act on failures, not just on success, depending on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval` probably isn't a good idea since the order is not guaranteed, therefore you could be sending requests every X amount of seconds that either come back all at once, not at all, or in a random order. You can use `setTimeout` in the callback to start another request in X amount of time:

```
function getStuff() {
    $.get('returnfunction.php', function(data) { 
        test=data;
        document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML=test; 
        setTimeout(getStuff, 5000); //Run this func again in 5 sec
    }); 
}
```