# return value from a jquery get callback function

Tags: callback, coffeescript, iced-coffeescript

It would be very useful to me if you could help me fix this function:

```
textParseQuery = (txtSnippet) ->    
    queryUrl = "http://localhost:8083/txtParse/#{txtSnippet}"
    console.log queryUrl
    callback = (response) => 
        parsed = $.parseJSON response
        companies = parsed.map (obj) -> new Company(obj.name, obj.addr)
        companies
    res = $.get queryUrl, {}, callback
    console.log res
```

I would like to fetch the results from the callback so that the `textParseQuery` function could return a value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable doesn't get returned from AJAX function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475269/variable-doesnt-get-returned-from-ajax-function)

Comment: I'd like to have an answer with idiomatic coffeescript code (use of the fat arrow ´=>´?)

Comment: You mean you don't know how to convert JS to and from CS ? Use JS then.

Comment: translating JS to coffeescript might mean not using peculiar features of latter. As I am trying to learn coffeescript, it'd be useful seeing how things are done differently in this language compared to javascript

Comment: There's no difference regarding callbacks or promises. CS only adds a cosmetic layer here, you have to understand how it works behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered [IcedCoffeeScript](http://maxtaco.github.io/coffee-script/) helps streamline the asynchronous control flow with `await` and `defer`. This is what I have tried to achieve. The code structure is how I pictured it

```
# Search for 'keyword' on twitter, then callback 'cb'
# with the results found.
search = (keyword, cb) ->
  host = "http://search.twitter.com/"
  url = "#{host}/search.json?q=#{keyword}&callback=?"
  await $.getJSON url, defer json
  cb json.results
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of a callback is it's asynchronous, your response comes in the callback, so you need to handle the rest of the execution from the callback (e.g., the `console.log res` is going to execute before your callback is called, since it's part of the same synchronous execution of your ajax call).

```
textParseQuery = (txtSnippet) ->    
    queryUrl = "http://localhost:8083/txtParse/#{txtSnippet}"
    callback = (response) -> 
        parsed = $.parseJSON response
        companies = parsed.map (obj) -> new Company(obj.name, obj.addr)

        # proceed from here
        console.log companies
    $.get queryUrl, {}, callback
```

Additional note: the fat arrow is unnecessary here, it's used to rebind what `this` refers to, but you aren't referencing `this` at all in your callback. If you're learning coffee, most editors will have plugin/modules to quickly compile coffee to JS, so use that to see what a given coffee syntax compiles to in JS (e.g., take a look at the diff between using `->` and `=>` when you compile your coffee)

Comment: Thanks. I did indeed managed to structure the code the way I had in mind with the help of IcedCoffeeScript