# Why my javascript function returning 'undefined' instead of my base64 encoded file?

Tags: javascript, return, base64, encode

I'm calling a function to encode in base64 an image, this function works because when I console.log the result IN the function, I do have a result. But when i try to get the result in an other function, the returned result is : "undefined".

Here is my javascript :

```
console.log(loadImageFileAsURL());

function loadImageFileAsURL(){
    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;

    if (filesSelected.length > 0){
        var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];
        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent){
            var result = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;

            //console.log(result) ; => gives a result
            return (result) ;
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }
}
```

[EDIT]=> Response @ [Variable doesn't get returned from AJAX function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475269/variable-doesnt-get-returned-from-ajax-function)

Here is my call :

```
loadImageFileAsURL(function test(res){
    console.log("===>:"+res);
});
```

Here is my function :

```
function loadImageFileAsURL(callback){
    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;

    if (filesSelected.length > 0){
        var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];
        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent){
            var result = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
            callback(result);
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: It did not think that it is the same question... So what is the answer ? I am doing an Ajax call ?

Comment: The problem is asynchronicity. See also [this QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475269/variable-doesnt-get-returned-from-ajax-function) which will probably be simpler to understand and apply

Comment: I didn't know it, i'll probably be ban because of my questions, why you just didn't tell me "Asynchronicity problem" instead of sending me in an other question and mark mine as duplicate ?! And I don't know what should I modify to make it works... I don't see any similarity betwin both posts.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, I just marked it as duplicate to reduce redundancy.

Comment: Here's an upvote because your question is clean.

Comment: Ok, thanx but, I'm not that good in javascript. Is it realy asynchronous ? I look in the other post for how to return the result but I still dont find...

Comment: Look at my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475269/variable-doesnt-get-returned-from-ajax-function)

Comment: Thanx for help. I made it work. I updated my post with the answer.